# How to switch high/low nibbles in a byte?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

How to switch between the first four bits and the other four bits in assembly. Example :

```
AL = 3fH
```

To

```
AL = f3H
```

Answer (score 3):

rotate by 4, either direction.

On 186 and later you can use `rol al, 4`, but on 8086 you need a count in CL for `rol al, cl`.

Or you have to repeat `rol al, 1` four times.